# Passing a list and setting it length as a default parameter in python

Tags: python, list, oop, methods

I have a class method from Python which is something like as follows:

```
def func(indel, nind=indel.length):
    #do_something
```

indel is a list.

I am getting an error when I am using this function definition. Is there any way I can do it?

Comment: use len(indel) to get length in python

Comment: Any reason why you need to pass a parameter at all? If you just want the length of the list, then why not just access it inside the function using `len`?

Comment: Actually, either I will be sending some length or in case, I do not send the length, I want the default to the length of the list

Answer (score 8, accepted):

While I am wondering why you are using a parameter at all, it is possible you may be wanting to do so because passing the length of the list is optional, such as if you want to operate on a small subset of the list. If that is the case, this is the code I would use:

```
def func(indel, length = None):
    #do_something
    if length is None: # By default, use the length of the list
        length = len(indel)
    # do whatever with indel and length

# test methods
test = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

func(test) # in this case, length = 5

func(test, 1) # in this case, length = 1
```

Comment: Good deduction of what the kwarg was needed for here. Just for good practice, I would set the default value to None instead.

Comment: Would `def func(..., length = None)` and `if length is None:` be preferable over a numerical value?

Comment: @ThomasKühn Yes, especially since Python supports negative indexing

Comment: @DeepSpace yes, just what I thought :)

Comment: The thing is, since I come from a C++ background (although I do have knowledge of Python), sometimes I use C++ practices unknowingly. In any case, the problem is solved now, and all is well.

Answer (score 1):

No. It's impossible (even if you used the correct syntax, ie `def func(indel, nind=len(indel)):`).

A function's default arguments are evaluated exactly ones: at function definition time (which is also why you should never use a mutable default argument). During the definition time `indel` is not yet defined, as indicated by the error you are probably getting: `NameError: name 'indel' is not defined`.

The only option is to "calculate" the list's length inside the function.

Comment: Actually, this would be pretty easy with a decorator.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ, probably, but for what? "saving" a call to `len`? doesn't worth it

Comment: Just thought I'd mention it since you said there's only one option.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ literally speaking, doing this with a decorator still counts as "inside the function" ;)

Answer (score 1):

Another way would be

```
    def setElementConnectivities(self,indel,nind=None):
        nind = len(indel) if nind is None else nind
        ind = np.copy(indel[0:nind])
        print(ind)
```

Comment: Unnecessary assignment of value `nind` to variable `nind` if `nind is not None`.   How about simply `ind = np.copy(indel[0:len(indel) if nind is None else nind])`?

Answer (score 0):

When you try to run this code, you will get the error `NameError: name 'indel' is not defined`.

When defining the function, `indel` was not yet assigned a value, it is only after the function will have been call that it will have one. Thus what you should do is the following.

```
def func(indel):
    nind=len(indel)
    #do_something
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do want to be able to pass a `nind` when calling the function, but would like the default to be the length of `indel` when not specifying `nind`, you could do something like this:

```
def func(indel, nind=None):
    nind = len(indel) if nind is None else nind
```

when you do not specify `nind` when calling, then `nind` is `None`, which subsequently changed to `len(indel)`

when yo DO specify `nind` when calling, then `nind` is the value of what you are calling with (exception is the "value" of `None`)

Answer (score 0):

A simple None is enough for you to specify the default length of the list in the function parameters:

```
>>> items = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> items[:None]
[1, 2, 3, 4]

>>> def return_list(items, end=None):
...     return items[:end]

>>> return_list(items)
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> return_list(items, end=2)
[1, 2]
```

None when specifying a slice is equivalent to the absence of a corresponding value. So items[:None] will work like items[:].

(I know this answer is no longer relevant to you. But maybe it will be useful for future readers).